# Parallelize prediction of model based on a big raster in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Is there a way to parallelize a blockSize() loop in R so that several blocks are predicted simultaneously?

Currently I use this lines to predict my raster which takes a long time because my stack is quite large (~400 layers):

```
  cs <- blockSize(tmpstack)  
eras <- writeStart(x = eras,filename = outfile,overwrite=TRUE)  
for(i in 1:cs$n){
    rawVal <- getValues(tmpstack,row = cs$row[i],nrows = cs$nrows[i])
    predv  <- predict(rf1,newdata=rawVal)
    eras   <- writeValues(eras,v = as.numeric(as.character(predv)),start =       cs$row[i])
  }
eras <- writeStop(eras)
```

Or is there any other possibility to make this faster? With this code I use only 10% of my available CPU-Power.

Answer (score 1):

See `raster::clusterR`, particularly the last example, as you can provide a parallelized function as an argument to `predict`.